# Display same custom error message for any string type error [ EXPRESS + JOI ]

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, joi

I have a two fields phone field and phoneCode field. I'm using "@hapi/joi" 16.1.8 version along with expressjs.

For custom error message I used .messages() method instead of .error() because its smiply straight foreward. This is the code I tried to validate with the Joi system:

```
const data = { phone, phoneCode };
const schema = Joi.object({
    phone: Joi.string().pattern(/^[0-9]{10}$/).required().messages({
        "string.base": "Sorry! It looks like something went wrong. Please try later.",
        "string.pattern.base": "Phone number must be a 10 digits number.",
        "string.empty": "Phone Number is not allowed to be empty."
    }),
    phoneCode: Joi.string().max(3).required().messages({ 
        "number": "Want to send default message if any error" 
    })
});

let validate = schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false });
```

I wanted to send only one default message whenerver error occoured in phoneCode keys. I also tried

```
"number.*": "Want to send default message if any error"
  OR
Joi.string().max(3).required().message("Want to send default message if any error") // It give Error: Cannot apply rules to empty ruleset
  OR
phoneCode: Joi.string().max(3).message("Want to send default message if any error" ).required() // This worked upto a limit, not working if i sent phoneCode empty.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I achieved the custom error message in JOI. Simply get the message from validate object. Its simple and working good.

```
const data = { phone, phoneCode };
const schema = Joi.object({
    phone: Joi.string().pattern(/^[0-9]{10}$/).required().messages({
        "string.base": "Sorry! It looks like something went wrong. Please try later",
        "string.pattern.base": "Phone number must be a 10 digits number",
        "string.empty": "Phone Number is not allowed to be empty",
        "any.required": "Phone Number is required"
    }),
    phoneCode: Joi.string().max(3).required().messages({ 
        "string.base": "Phone code must be valid",
        "string.empty": "Phone code must be valid",
        "string.max": "Phone code must be valid",
        "any.required": "Phone code must be valid"
    })
});

let validate = schema.validate(data);

if (!validate || validate.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
   console.error(`[URL: ${req.originalUrl}] [ERROR:${JSON.stringify(validate.error.details)}]`);
   return SendResponse.sendErrorMessage(res, validate.error.details[0].message);
}
```

Comment: But you wanted one error for all failures in a property. How is this code going to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is not directly possible right now from Joi. You can use `.error(new Error(errMsg))` to send back single error in case of issue in phoneCode:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const joiSchema = Joi.object({
    phone: Joi.string().pattern(/^[0-9]{10}$/).required().messages({
        "string.base": "Sorry! It looks like something went wrong. Please try later.",
        "string.pattern.base": "Phone number must be a 10 digits number.",
        "string.empty": "Phone Number is not allowed to be empty."
    }),
    phoneCode: Joi.string().max(3).required().error(new Error("Want to send default message if any error"))
}).error((errors) => new Error(errors.join(' ')));

const { error, value } = joiSchema.validate({ phone: 123, phoneCode: null }, { abortEarly: false });
console.log(error, value);
```

Outputs:

```
Error: Sorry! It looks like something went wrong. Please try later. Error: Want to send default message if any error
Object {phone: 123, phoneCode: null}
```

But remember that Joi sends back `ValidationError` in case of `.messages()`, but now it will send back `Error`. You can format your errors as per your requirement, I have simply joined them with a space at the end.

RunKit with executable code: https://runkit.com/rvypandey/5e394a3b78e4df0013483771